# Is it correct to say "I will start looking into it tomorrow"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which one of the following sounds grammatically correct? I'm leaning towards the first.

`I will start looking into it tomorrow.`

`I will start looking into it beginning tomorrow.`

`I will start looking into it from tomorrow.`

I can also say `I will look into it tomorrow` but I'd like to retain `I will start looking into` in the sentence.

Thanks

Comment: They're all grammatically correct. #2 is a little redundant, and #3 leaves me wondering what's being said (what does it mean to start something *from* tomorrow?), but that's a meaning problem, not grammar.  I suggest you stick with #1: short and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I agree. The first option is the best. 'Beginning' in the second option is superfluous because it means pretty much the same as 'start' and 'from' in the third option is superfluous too (if the starting point is tomorrow, 'from' is already implied).

If you chose to say "I will look into it tomorrow" instead, this would still be correct, but your sentence would have a slightly different meaning. The first - "I will start ..." implies that it will take you more than one day to complete the task of looking into it, whereas the second "I will look ..." implies that you can complete the looking into in one day.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? I can't see anything wrong with it, so an explanation would be appreciated.